# HttpWebRequest Automatic sending required HttpRequests

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am using HTTPWebRequest to simulate POST request to login to a website. but when using firebug to track what the browser is doing during the login i find that it makes some GetRequests after that login.

So what i am looking for is how to make my POST Request automatically do that GET Requests ?

someone told me to use the JS Functions but i am totally clueless of this.

```
private static async Task<byte[]> LoginAsync(string username, string password)
{
    var postData = new NameValueCollection();

    var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}/", ServerName));

    postData.Add("name", username);
    postData.Add("password", password);
    postData.Add("login", ParseLoginId(await GetPage("login.php")));

    return await HttpHandler.UploadValuesTaskAsync(uri, postData);
}
```

MY HTTP HANDLER

```
private CookieContainer _mContainer = new CookieContainer();

protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
{
    var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
    if (request is HttpWebRequest)
    {
        (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = _mContainer;
    }
    return request;
}

public void ClearCookies()
{
    _mContainer = new CookieContainer();
}
```

I am using the code above to send the POST Request but the problem is it does not totally simulates what the browser do... so it does not autamatically send the required GET requests after the login.

Comment: Can you post your code or more information please?

Comment: I need help also i don't wanna start new thread for that help...

Answer (score 0):

The preceding GET requests are likely Location header redirects.

Why not use the System.Net.WebClient class. 
[C# Console/Server access to web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888809/c-sharp-console-server-access-to-web-site)
The link shows you how to extend the WebClient to persist cookie information.

Comment: well that extended class do the rest of GET Requests just like the browser is doing the...

Comment: in the browser right after the post request i find 3 Get requests are made.

Comment: @Torlan Other - AllowAutoRedirect is set to true in WebClient instances http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: But take a look at my httphandler (it uses webclient) but when i track the connection of my application i see it is only making the get requests and not the other GET ones

Comment: i am sorry if am annoying you but i really need some more help :D